# database structure for multiple ingredients

Tags: mysql, database

Below I have a basic database for recipes. I want to have a table of ingredients that are static, and each time a user adds an ingredient 3 ids gets put into the recipe_ingredient table, 1 for the new recipe_ingredient, 1 for the recipe its for and 1 for the ingredient. I want to know if this is practical or what would be a good way to store ingredients for recipes.

```
---RECIPES---          ---INGREDIENTS---
+-> ID:                    ID: <-+
|   NAME:                  NAME: |
|   PHOTO:                       |
|                                |
|  ---RECIPE_INGREDIENT---       |
|        ID:                     |
+------+ RECIPE_ID:              |
         INGREDIENT_ID: +--------+
         AMMOUNT:
```

Comment: Looks good. As far as I know,  this is the best approach to store many-to-many relationships in a relational database.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks for the input :) - and then if i want pull all data id do a join and group wouldnt i? every join ive tried still gives me 5 rows of recipies

Comment: For a given recipe, a normal join (`RECIPE_INGREDIENT` joined to `RECIPE` and `INGREDIENT`) will return the same number of records as there are ingredients in that recipe. It's relational data, not hierarchical.